# Run FME with subprocess Modul

Tags: python, fme-form, subprocess

This is working but i have no idear how to give user_parameter to the process.

```
import subprocess 

args = [r"C:\Program Files\FME2021\fme.exe","test.fmw"]

subprocess.Popen(args)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as you noticed, you use

```
--[parameter name] [value]
```

In fact, if you run the workspace in FME Workbench, the first lines of the log window give you the full command to use with all parameters:

```
INFORM| Command line to run this workspace:
INFORM|     "C:\Program Files\FME2022.1\fme.exe" "G:\Folder\Workspace.fmw"
INFORM|       --SourceDataset_SPATIALITE_NATIVE "$(FME_MF_DIR_USERTYPED)ParksDataset.sqlite"
INFORM|       --MODE "Flatten One Level"
```

Of course, you can choose not to pass a value to every parameter, as necessary.

Answer (score -1):

args = r'C:"Program Files"\FME2021\fme.exe test.fmw --name somethingt'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).